How can I resolve PPA repository errors when using WSL 2 with Ubuntu 24.04
I am using WSL 2 with Ubuntu 24.04. I exported Ubuntu and imported it to my D drive since I had more space there. While trying to add repositories (PPA), I get errors.
How can I add the repositories without errors?
When I use sudo apt-get update, the errors appear again, and I cannot update it.
I tried changing the nameserver to 8.8.8.8 in resolv.conf, but it didn't work.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases
Repository: 'Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnuradio/gnuradio-releases/ubuntu/
Suites: noble
Components: main
'
Description:
PPA for GNU Radio Tagged Releases
More info: https://launchpad.net/~gnuradio/+archive/ubuntu/gnuradio-releases
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnuradio/gnuradio-releases/ubuntu noble InRelease
Err:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnuradio/gnuradio-releases/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125....]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnuradio/gnuradio-releases/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Trying to add another PPA in Ubuntu and I get a similiar error:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniestevez/gr-satellites
Repository: 'Types: deb
URIs: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/daniestevez/gr-satellites/ubuntu/
Suites: noble
Components: main
'
Description:
gr-satellites is a GNU Radio out-of-tree module that contains a collection of  decoders for Amateur satellites. It supports most popular protocols, such as AX.25,  the GOMspace NanoCom U482C and AX100 modems, an important part of the CCSDS stack, the AO-40 protocol used in the FUNcube satellites, and several ad-hoc protocols  used in other satellites.

More info: https://launchpad.net/~daniestevez/+archive/ubuntu/gr-satellites
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/daniestevez/gr-satellites/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Err:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/daniestevez/gr-satellites/ubuntu noble Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125....]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/daniestevez/gr-satellites/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


You installed Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat).
The repositories you tried to add do not support Ubuntu 24.04. The first one - ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases - supports up to Ubuntu 22.04 and the second - ppa:daniestevez/gr-satellites - supports up to Ubuntu 23.10. Both should be considered abandoned at this point.
Yours is a typical beginner mistake, not checking whether the third party repositories (PPA) are still being maintained for what Ubuntu releases they have content available. Hint: Just google the PPA name/string as above, the first result will be the actual PPA's webpage (e.g. https://launchpad.net/~gnuradio/+archive/ubuntu/gnuradio-releases) where you'll see a "choose your Ubuntu version" dropdown menu. Click it to list all the Ubuntu releases supported by said PPA. Do NOT add any that doesn't support your own release.
The first step should be to remove the repositories you added. So, run the same commands to add but now with the --remove argument. E.G.:
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:daniestevez/gr-satellites

Now, the first software you're supposedly after - GNU Radio - is available in the official Ubuntu 24.04 repositories, no need to add a third party repository (the instructions at the developer's webpage are for older Ubuntu releases).
Installation: sudo apt install gnuradio
The same for the other module, just install from the official repositories: sudo apt install gr-satellites
